# Fill materialize javascript autocomplete data with twig object

Tags: javascript, symfony, autocomplete, twig

I'm working on an application and now I'm messing with the Materialize autocomplete plugin.

Now I would like to parse an array of twig objects (let's say Customers), and to create an array in JS like this one :

```
var customersAutocomplete = [
        {
        key: 1,
        Title: "John Doe",
        label: 'John'},
        {
        key: 2,
        title: "Ulrich",
        label: 'John'},
        {
        key: 3,
        label: 'James'}
        ];
```

Autocompletion is from a global JS files and looks like this :

```
$.fn.autocomplete = function (options) {
      // Defaults
      var defaults = {
        data: {customersAutocomplete},
        limit: Infinity,
        onAutocomplete: null,
        minLength: 1
      };
```

Comment: if you using symfony  you can make your controller pass this data as a json to your twig as a variable which  can then be accessible in your twig  via javascript.

Ideally , i'll rather send an AJAX call to a specific action that would return the list as json.

Comment: @RaymondA Thanks, I'll definitly try that !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to @RaymondA's comment, you can use Twig to do that directly in your template if your `customers` object has the right structure already :

```
<!-- views/your.view.html.twig -->
<script>   
    customersAutocomplete = {{ customers|json_encode() }};
</script>
```

And then use `customersAutocomplete` in your js file :

```
$.fn.autocomplete = function (options) {
      // Defaults
      var defaults = {
        data: customersAutocomplete,
        limit: Infinity,
        onAutocomplete: null,
        minLength: 1
      };
```